# Java Scanner Code If-then-else

Tags: java, if-statement

My **`if-then-else`** statement is always outputting the **`else`** outcome

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class NiallScanner {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    System.out.println("Hello, What is your name?");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String yourName = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Is your name: "+yourName + "?");

    Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String isCorrect = scanner1.nextLine();

    if (isCorrect ==  "Yes")
    {
        System.out.println("Thank you for your confirmation!");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Retry please.");

    }

}
```

Any ideas why guys? I'm really new to java btw, so I may be overlooking basic coding errors.

Comment: Read [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `"Yes".equals(isCorrect);`, `==` compares object references, not content. Two different `Strings` can have the same content.

Alternatively you can use [String.intern()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern%28%29) to obtain unique references from the pool of strings; those can be safely compared using the `==` operator:

```
"Yes" == isCorrect.intern();
```

While both methods work, I would advice you to go with the first one. Use `equals` to compare objects and `==` to compare primitives.

Check out the [Working example](http://ideone.com/I93gsp).

Answer (score 1):

Use `equals()` method instead, because `==` compare object reference the bit it contain to see if two object are refering to the same object. But `equals()` method compare the value instead. so in this case you should do: `"Yes".equals(isCorrect)`

If you want to check if two object are refering to the same object for example:

```
Object1 x = new Object1();
Object2 y = x;

if(x == y) {
//This will return true because 'y' is refering to object 'x' so both has the bit to  access the object on memory.
}
```

But if you want to check by value for example:

```
String hola1 = "hola";
String hola2 = "hola";
if(hola1.equals(hola2)){
 //Return true because both has the same value.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use equals method to Compare strings.== will compare the references not the content.Please find the corrected program.

```
public class NiallScanner {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, What is your name?");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String yourName = scanner.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Is your name: "+yourName + "?");

    Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String isCorrect = scanner1.nextLine();


    if (isCorrect.equals("Yes"))
    {
        System.out.println("Thank you for your confirmation!");
    }
    else
    {

        System.out.println("Retry please.");

    }
}

}
```